# md5 file encryption moved to a different server

Tags: php, md5

I havea site that cached and compresses data then saves it to a directory sorted by the MD5 filename.  The server was shut-down and I moved it to a new server.  The problem is the new server cannot find the old data and the http://exmple.com has changed location.  Is there a fix for this?

Data is sorted with this line of code

```
    function get_part_url($part) {
            $url = 'http://example.com.com&part='.$part;

            return $url;
    }

    function get_cache_file($url) {
        $xid = md5($url);

        $gendir = CACHE_ROOT . substr($xid, 0, 1) . '/'. substr($xid, 1, 2);

        if(!is_dir($gendir)) {
            mkdir($gendir, 0777, true);
            }

        return $gendir . '/' . $xid;
    }
```

Comment: If the old server was shut down, the data is gone. If you have a backup, great - but if not, your date is gone.

Comment: There is no "fix" for this - you need to figure out where the data is stored on the new server.  Are you sure the data exists on the new server?  If it's not there you're out of luck.  If it's there make sure the script has permission to access the data and feed the right path to your script.

Comment: `The server was shut-down and I moved it to a new server` does `it` also include those files?

Comment: I do have a backup of the old data, but the url is encrypted.  Is there a way to uncompress it- rename it- then recompress using gzcompress & md5 encrypt the correct url?